# Converting C++11 code into the C++98

Tags: c++, c++11, c++98

The code:

```
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(pRes))) {
        TMPTable temp = {};
        if (row[0]) temp.con = strtoul(row[0], NULL, 10);
        std::vector<MATable>.push_back(temp);
}
```

Error on the line with `TMPTable temp = {};`:

`in C++98 'temp' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'`

Another problem is :

`std::ostringstream query;`

Giving the error:

`aggregate 'std::ostringstream query' has incomplete type and cannot be defined`

I have tried the solutions on google, but havent found any working one... Always ending up with an error. Could you guys point me in the right direction?

Comment: The second one looks like you didn't include the header (which is just as prone to error in C++11).

Comment: That first example has a syntax error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to include `<sstream>` to get a definition of `std::ostringstream`. To address the initialization you can simply use

```
TMPtable tmp = TMPtable();
```

Comment: Yaay! I was getting headache, both errors are gone now, thank you Dietmar! <can accept the answer within 6 minutes)

Comment: If `TMPtable` has a default constructor, you can just write `TMPtable tmp;`, and it will be correctly initialized.